# IBM Worklight - Shell Component

Tags: shell, ibm-mobilefirst

When I have created a shell component, inside the shell component common folder there is folder called preview. I need to know what is the use of this folder. I am trying to understand about it using the following point specified in IBM modules.

```
preview: can be used to implement native functionality stubs for simulation in the Worklight Console preview instead of receiving exceptions
```

Still i am not having any clear idea about this. Can anyone give a clear idea about this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the main idea of the preview folder for shell component is to simulate its native behaviour, let's say for example you want to you the Google Maps API on a given area.

For the one developing the shell they do not have the final App, to test its behaviour. So, they can create some simulation such as a picture for a Map or a Picture of a Android TOAST, to allow them to work in the shell it self.